# How to set ownership for apache under linux (centOS)?

Tags: linux, permissions, centos, prestashop

I want to install and use prestashop but now it only works correctly when I set permissions to 777 (I can login to the server via shell with root privileges). While installing I get this error "recursive write permissions for apache user on..." and only works for permissions set to 777. I don't like this idea because after installation I can't even change back to 755 or 775. I also get problem partly solved when I change the user ownership to apache but then I can't do anything with my ftp client with that folder.

The user owner is ftp and the group owner is psacln? How should I change the membership of the folders so I can work both through ftp and allow apache to do things with presta files? (and of course have the permission set not higher then to 775). BTW, do I have to restart a server when adding or removing user's membership of the group?

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problem.

ssh root@ip_address

chown -R www-data:ftp /var/www/prestashop

You don't need to restart the server.

Optional :
service apache2 reload

Comment: Can you explain the first line: ssh root@ip_address, what it's for?

Comment: ssh root@ip_address is the command you type to connect to your linux server on your terminal.

Comment: ok, I use putty but thx. With the other part I get problem too. I changed the www-data to apache because I don't have such a user (getent passwd) but still I can't work with ftp client. Giving ls -l command I get the user: xxx (which I use to log via ftp) and the group: psacln. This way I can use ftp (copy, delete files) but presta doesn't work correctly. If change user: xxx to apache, then presta is fine but I can't use ftp (delete files - Permission denied).

Comment: I also tired like this: I left user at it is: xxx and added the user apache to psacln group and changed permissions folder 775, files 664 but presta still has problem with permissions.

Comment: I think I have managed this. I've added the user : xxx to the group: apache, and then I've changed only the group from psacln to apache recursively to all folders and files. Folder's permissions are 775, files 664 and it seems to be working fine. Some people might have apache configured as www-data or other.